# Service Fabric Guest Executable hosting and graceful stop

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a .NET 4.6.2 console application I want to host in Service Fabric.
My application is listening on console input events for administration tasks.

The most important one is 'q' **to stop the application** - but **in a graceful manner**.

**Is it somehow possible to also have this functionality in Service Fabric with a guest executable?**
 Of course not on 'q button pressed' but rather on service deleted or whatever events there are.

If there is no way to achieve this kind of integration with a guest executable - which project template do you recommend to build upon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stateful or stateless service class:

```
class MyService : StatefulService /* or StatelessService */
{
    protected override Task OnCloseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // your graceful shutdown code goes here
    }
}
```

But execution of that method is not guaranteed, for instance when the hosting VM unexpectedly dies.

Comment: I thought about using a a stateful service project template for this exercise. I wasn't sure if that's the best way. It feels wrong (mis-use of template) :-)

Answer (score 3):

Service Fabric sends a Ctrl-C signal to the guest executable process before killing it, allowing for graceful shutdown (Unless you enable the `EnableActivateNoWindow` [setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings)). You can use the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event or the Win32 `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` function to get a notification. Note the exe must be compiled as a console app for this to work.

Comment: Using the guest executable approach I absolutely can not get hold of the Ctrl-C signal.  I have a compiled console app.  Where is this documented specifically?  Are there any extra <exehost> settings I need.  I am not using the ServiceFabric SDK at all (remaining completely agnostic to better our upgrade path options)v

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, would be to programmatically delete the service when you're done with it, using [DeleteServiceAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.deleteserviceasync.aspx)
You can recreate it too, using [CreateServiceAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.createserviceasync.aspx)